# Solution of $\tan^{-1}(1) = 3x - 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I am asked to solve 
$$
\tan^{-1}(1) = 3x - 1
$$
for which the answer is $\dfrac{3.14+4}{12} \,\mathrm{rad}$.
I am unable to reach this only to attain the value $0.588 \,\mathrm{rad}$.

Comment: I think that $\frac{\pi+4}{12} = 0.588$. Please see if this is true.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to reach the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

That's a linear equation!

As $\arctan 1=\dfrac\pi4$, it is equivalent to
$$3x-1=\frac\pi4\iff x=\frac13\Bigl(\frac\pi4+1\Bigr)=\frac{\pi+4}{12}.$$
Numerically, one finds $x\approx 0.595$, not $0.588$.